# Why does the image disappear when using Bootstrap media object in a presenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In Rails 3.2 app I have a index view that is built around Twitter Bootstrap's media object component. I'm trying to tidy up this up and move some of the code into a presenter (http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch).

I'm having a strange issue whereby a div is totally disappearing from the rendered markup. Is there a mistake in my code?

```
def render_object
  content_tag(:div, class: "row") do
    div_for(object, class: "object-container") do
      content_tag(:div, class: "media") do
        link_to(object, class: "pull-left") do
          image_tag(object.image_url(:thumb), class: "media-object") if object.image?
        end
        content_tag(:div, class: "media-body") do
          link_to(object.user.name, object.user) 
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I load the page, the image and its href link are nowhere to be seen in the markup. Strangely the `.media-body` div and its content are present.

If I comment out the 3 lines describing the `.media-body` div, then the linked image is rendered.

I don't understand why this should be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight the answer to this is obvious, but it stumped me for a long time so adding an answer in case it will be useful for others.

Basically the content_tag will only return the last item, as per any ruby function. So the secret is to concatenate the link and content methods.

```
def render_object
  content_tag(:div, class: "row") do
    div_for(object, class: "object-container") do
      content_tag(:div, class: "media") do
        html = link_to(object, class: "pull-left") do
          image_tag(object.image_url(:thumb), class: "media-object") if object.image?
        end
        html += content_tag(:div, class: "media-body") do
          link_to(object.user.name, object.user) 
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

note the `html =`